# nodejs - typescript not working in javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am following this youtube tutorial,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnvKXcSI7yk&ab_channel=edureka%21

[image]

But in my project, the typescript is not working

```
app.post('/new_contact', function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var phone = req.body.phone;

    /* doesn't work
    db.insert((name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true), phone, function(err,header ){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error creating database "+ req.body.dbname);
            return;     
         }
         return res.send("contact created successfully");
        })

        */

//works
    db.insert((name, phone, true), phone, function(err,header ){
            if(err){
                res.send("Error creating database "+ req.body.dbname);
                return;     
             }
             return res.send("contact created successfully");
            })
    });
```

When I follow the code in the video I am getting the following error:

[image]

Looking forward to hearing from you soon!

Comment: Are you sure that the file has `.ts` extension?

Comment: No, in tutorial, its .js, infact, all files are js

Comment: Your tutorial is wrong.

Comment: i think of it also, i followed the steps and once I launched the express, its showing me other errors. i am moving to udemy course

Answer (score 1):

Bro , you have a mistake

for `db.insert` you should provide an **object** as argument.

instead of :

`db.insert((name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true), phone, function(err,header ){`

write :

```
db.insert({name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true}, phone, function(err,header ){
```

( replace "(" with "{" )

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. Replace `(` with `{`.

***db.insert takes object {} as an argument.***

```
db.insert({name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true}, phone, function(err,header ){
<---somecode--->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you interact with DB, always send an Object. In this case, u need to send name, phone and crazy in the object.

```
app.post('/new_contact', function(req, res){
var name = req.body.name;
var phone = req.body.phone;
db.insert(({name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true}), phone, function(err,header ){
    if(err){
        res.send("Error creating database "+ req.body.dbname);
        return;     
     }
     return res.send("contact created successfully");
    })
})
```

Comment: What are the extra `()` for around this `{name:name, phone:phone, crazy:true}` object?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a really close look, you will see that he uses brackets `{ }` and not paranthesis `( )`

Change this:

```
db.insert((name, phone, true)
```

to this:

```
db.insert({ name, phone, true }
```

Its not an typescript or express.js error, its more about lack of javascript knowledge